Unable to Display .OBJ Model with A-Frame and AR.js Using <a-marker> with obj-model
I’m trying to display an OBJ model using A-Frame and AR.js. The camera opens but the OBJ model doesn’t appear.
The OBJ file were rendered from Meshroom 2023.3, I copied from the Texturing folder.
Here's the code I'm using:
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.6.1/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://jeromeetienne.github.io/AR.js/aframe/build/aframe-ar.js"></script>

<body style="margin : 0px; overflow: hidden;">
    
  <a-scene embedded arjs="sourceType: webcam;  markersAreaEnabled: true;">
      <a-marker preset="hiro">
        <a-entity 
        obj-model="obj: url(https://nft-images-bucket2.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/texturedMesh.obj); 
        mtl: url(https://nft-images-bucket2.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/texturedMesh.mtl)">
         </a-entity>
    </a-entity>
      </a-marker>
      <a-entity camera></a-entity>  </a-scene>
</body>

